# how do I know the time involved in updating the firmware of my samsung I5801 phone via KIES

Tags: samsung-galaxy-apollo, samsung-kies, updates

The [official update for samsung I5801 is available now](http://www.themanmade.com/samsung-galaxy/samsung-galaxy-i5801-froyo-2-2-now-officially-out-in-india-via-kies).

**Has anyone done it before (using KIES, any samsung phone)?** 
**How long it will take** to update the firmware via Samsung Kies pc suite?
 
What are the **additional things to do** before and after I update my firmware? 
(* I have taken backup of my contacts, messages and applications on the phone's memory card
 * I will reset my phone before and after updating the firmware using the settings -> factory reset option)

If something goes wrong then what can be done to revert.

Please help me as I don't want to fall in trouble after attempting an update.

Thanks

Comment: +1 because you alerted me to the update for this phone. YES! Have you succeeded yet?

Comment: @amir75: Yes. I was able to update successfully. Without any hiccups or glitch. I must say that Samsung has done a real good job by creating such a no-pains update system for it's phones. Awesome.

Comment: Well done. I couldn't get Kies to recognise my phone, so I'm stuck. I'm not in India, so maybe that's why. Ah well, good for you anyway.

Comment: Oh, could you pls specify your Windows version? Kies won't recognise my phone on Windows 7, so I'm wondering if it's worth trying another OS. Thanks

Comment: @amir75: I use windows XP professional with Service Pack 2. You can do it on any of your friend's machine having windows xp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual update should take at very most half an hour, the download time may vary though.  Other than a backup, I don't see what else you'd need to do.

If you have trouble, come back and post a separate question with details.  The update usually either fails entirely (in which case you can try again) or works fine, you shouldn't end up in some half-updated broken state.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. :-) actually I tried it yesterday and everything went fine. It took around 40 minutes for the update process to complete. Posting the screenshots for other's reference.

Answer (score 2):

Updated the firmware successfully. :)

Took almost 40 minutes for the upgrade process to finish completely.

**After the update I was amazed to see that all the settings, programs, contacts and accounts were there. I didn't have to restore from the backup that I took earlier.**

Froyo is much faster that eclair.

Hope this answer is helpful to those looking to upgrade their firmware but feared (like me) the risk of data being lost or phone malfunctioning.

Go ahead and upgrade your firmware. You will love it.

Here are the screenshots 
[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]
[image: Final success screen]